# Why Java Web Application is development with Java SE SDK

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Why we always say we used JAVA EE to develop the web application. But we used Java SE's SDK in development, compile the code and even in the application server, Java version alway Java SE?

Comment: To expand on Abhishek's answer below, Java SE provides the base tools -- like the compiler -- and Java EE extends those tools with extra libraries and a framework.  There's no sense in Java EE duplicating what Java SE already has, so Java EE is basically just the extra bits you need for web work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java EE is a superset of Java SE. Java EE has a lot of features like Multi-tier architecture, EJBs and various other specifications which can be followed in developing web applications but if you are not using them you can as well say you developed the web app using Java. 
Few Key differences between the two:

- Java SE is the core Java programming language. The Java EE platform
  is built on top of SE platform, used especially for large-scale
  applications.
- SE defines everything from the basic types and objects of the Java
  programming language, hence provides all core functionalities. The
  Java EE platform provides an API and runtime environment for
  developing and running large-scale applications. Java SE platform
  consists of a virtual machine, development tools, deployment
  technologies and other libraries commonly used in Java. Java EE
  consists of Enterprise JavaBeans, Java Server Pages, Servlets.
- SE has no separation of code into different layers, while EE is a
  multi-tier application, this helps in application more robust, and
  more secure. Typical Java EE application has following layers:
- **The Client Tier** Client tier is where user interaction happens.
  Applications in this tier access Java Server, which is usually
  located on a different machine. A client sends a request, the server
  processes this request and sends a response back to the client.
- **The Web Tier** This layer handles the interaction between the client
  and the business tier.
- **The Business Tier** This tier consists of business logic and all core
  functionalities.

More differences can be found [here](https://blog.overops.com/java-ee-vs-java-se-has-oracle-given-up-on-enterprise-software/).